# Create object from fileScan param

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am struggling to properly execute this code. Everything seems to work, except where I call the addBook function. I am trying to pass in a CSV and initialize it.

```
public void addBook(Book book) {
    books[currIndex] = book;
    currIndex++;
}   

public void setNumBooks(int num) {
     //how many books
    numBooks = num;
    books = new Book[numBooks]; //init array
    }
```

This next function is where I am running into issues

```
public void addBooksFromFile(String filename) {
    File f = new File(filename);
    

    try{
        Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(f); //set semi colon delimiter
        numBooks = fileScan.nextInt();
        setNumBooks(numBooks);
        String line;

        while(fileScan.hasNextLine())
            line = fileScan.nextLine();
            String[] splitArray = line.split("; ");

            for(int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++){

                //addBook();
            }          
    }
    catch (IOException e) //input output exception 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

When I try to pass splitArray[i] it states string is not compat with book, which makes sense. How can I fix this to work properly?

Comment: Note that I fixed the String line = "", it was not init.

Comment: You need to call `Book`'s constructor and only then pass it to `addBook(book)` method.

Comment: So the book is initialized in the array, it is declared earlier in the code. What you area saying is I need to call the Book in that function?

Comment: Pro Tip: Copy and paste the exact error message into your question. While we can probably guess what the problem is here, summarizing the error message leaves out important details.

Comment: Also, you can usually copy/paste the error into google and find someone else has posted the exact same question here before.

Comment: Code `new Book[numBooks]` initializes the array, not its elements. Yes, you need to call in loop: `books[i] = new Book(bookName);`

Answer (score 1):

The specific solution to your conundrum highly depends on the implementation of the `Book` class.

Java is a strongly typed language, therefore you must adhere to the type of the parameter that the method expects as an argument.

```java
splitArray[i] // this return a String, which is not a Book
```

Assuming your Book class looks like this:

```
public class Book {
    
    final String text;

    public Book(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Your for loop iteration should be changed to the following:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++){
                final Book book = new Book(splitArray[i]);
                addBook(book);
            }
```

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you!